# Group stream(list) of objects to a map-> based on object type -> and then filter based on Map Keys using Predicates

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following objects:

```
abstract class Fizz {

}

class Foo extends Fizz {

}

class Bar extends Fizz {

}

class Buzz extends Fizz {

}
```

Then i have a list of **Fizz** objects

```
List<Fizz> elements;
```

I want to group this elements in a

```
Map <Fizz, List<Fizz>> mapFizz;
```

And in the end be able to retrieve Map values as following:

```
List<Foo> fooList = mapFizz.get(Foo.class);
List<Bar> barList = mapFizz.get(Bar.class);
List<Buzz> buzzList = mapFizz.get(Buzz.class);
```

I want to be able to iterate over the Map keySet and check if an instance of the Buzz exist and then do something:

```
boolean buzzExists = mapFizz.keySet().stream()
           .anyMatch(theKey -> instanceof Buzz.class)
```

```
buzzExists = true
```

when i am able to do

```
List<Buzz> buzzList = mapFizz.get(Buzz.class)
```

and also be able to add new key that extends Fizz;

```
class Look extends Fizz{
}

mapFizz.keyValues().add(Look.class);
```

What i've tried is this, and it works partially:

```
List<Fizz> elements = a list with many Fizz elements;

Map<? extends Class<? extends Fizz>, List<Fizz>> mapedElements = elements.stream()
.collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(
             Fizz::getClass
        )
     )
```

The above solution partially works. I can retrieve the elements of the map with:

```
List<Foo> fooList = mapedElements.get(Foo.class);
```

But all of the keys are instance of the Class.class and i can't do:

```
mapedElements.keySet().stream()
                      .anyMatch( aKey -> aKey instanceof Foo.class) //always false
```

even if I am able to do

```
List<Foo> fooElements = mapedElements.get(Foo.class)
```

---

The workaround that i've found would be:

```
Map<String, List<Fizz>> mapedElements = elements.stream()
.collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(
             element -> element.getClass().getName()
        )
     )
```

and then the key would be the **import path** of each class that extends Fizz: *com.package.folder.Foo*

But i wanted to check if maybe there is a cleaner solution
Thanks

Comment: no, it's just an action that i want to do, if the predicate matches.
basically i want ```.anyMatch()``` to return ```true``` if the instance of ```Buzz.class``` exist in the key set. 

My issue is that the key set is formed of keys of type ```Class```

Comment: Do you know about the `containsKey` method on `Map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is almost there:

```
Map<Class<? extends Fizz>, List<Fizz>> map = elements.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Fizz::getClass, HashMap::new, Collectors.toList())
);
```

You don't need `? extends Class<? extends Fizz>`. Just `Class<? extends Fizz>` is fine. Also note that you should use the overload of `groupingBy` that allows you to specify a map supplier, since by default, the map returned by `groupingBy` is not guaranteed to be mutable, and you seem to want to add things to the map later on.

Just to clarify, this is how you could add a new key to the map:

```
map.put(AnotherFizzSubclass.class, new ArrayList<>());
```

There is no `keyValues()` method in `Map` :)

To check if a key is in the map, just use `containsKey`:

```
if (map.containsKey(Foo.class)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

This will `doSomething()` only if the map has exactly `Foo.class`. If you also want to `doSomething` in case the map has a subclass of `Foo` (similar to the behaviour of `instanceof`), then you can do:

```
if (map.keySet().stream().anyMatch(Foo.class::isAssignableFrom)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already noticed. Maybe it’s worth showing examples of valid modifications, as the OP’s idea of doing `mapFizz.keyValues().add(Look.class);` wouldn’t work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The missing part that i wanted to most was `Foo.class::isAssignableForm`  this allows me to create a predicate that i can extend later.
=============
I will want to check the key agains something like:
`Predicate<Fizz> isFoo = Foo.class::isAssignableFrom;
Predicate<Fizz> isBuzz = Buzz.class::isAssignableFrom;
Predicate<Fizz> isBar  = Bar.class::isAssignableFrom;

Predicate<Fizz> isFooOrBarOrBuzz = isFoo.or(isBuzz).or(isBuzz);`
and then do:

`if (map.keySet().stream().anyMatch(isFooOrBarOrBuzz )) {
    doSomething();
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the `Hashmap` and override the Class to make it polymorphic.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Optional;

public class PolyHashMap<K extends Class<?>,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return findClass((K)key).isPresent();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        var entry = findClass((K)key);
        return entry.map(Entry::getValue).orElse(null);
    }

    private Optional<Entry<K,V>> findClass(K key) {
        return entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().isAssignableFrom(key))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

Then you can use this map in your program as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PolyHashMap<Class<?>, List<Fizz>> map = new PolyHashMap<>();
    map.put(Buzz.class, Arrays.asList(new Buzz(),new Buzz()));
    map.put(Foo.class, Arrays.asList(new Foo()));

    System.out.println(map.get(Buzz.class).size());
    System.out.println(map.get(Foo.class).size());

}
```